# Cypress use local api server

Tags: testing, cypress

maybe somebody use cypress for testing e2e flows together with backend API calls without some mocks.

I have a trouble right now, I want to use my local API from simple Laravel server like
`http://127.0.0.1:8000`, but all my XHR request aborted when I run tests. After some investigations I understood that if I change request baseUrl to `https://example.com` then requests works fine.

[Example of XHR aborting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q4k2.png)

I already set `chromeWebSecurity` to `false`.

**Cypress version**: 4.0.2

cypress.json

```
{
  "viewportWidth": 1920,
  "viewportHeight": 1000,
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
  "watchForFileChanges": false,
  "integrationFolder": "cypress/build/cypress/integration",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "blacklistHosts": [],
  "env": {
    "host": "http://localhost:4200",
    "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"
  }
}
```